# Bootstrap glyphicon-menu-hamburger not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, glyphicons

Here is clearly defined bootstrap icon for hamburger menu: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs

If I use it in my html this icon is not showing, but others icon are:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a matter of glyphicon version in your bootstrap version for it will be always updated so use the same version. you can check it here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/. it looks it is compatible in v3.3.2 and check yours.

Other possibilities:

1. missing glyphicons font in fonts directoryc.
2. Changes found in path of directory

Comment: Yes, I was using version 3.2.0 instead of 3.3.2. However, I used font awesome icon instead of bootstrap, which looks much better than bootstrap's blurry icon.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I love the old one :p

Answer (score 6):

Jean Gkol has a point, because it looks like that your issue is probably down to your Bootstrap version. I tested at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tzIQxUdNsa) your code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

and it worked with version 3.3.2. However, once I changed the version to 3.3.1, 3.3.0 or 3.2.0 the glyphicon didn't show up. So it looks like that the hamburger glyphicon is a quite new image in the Bootstrap Component pack.