# Glyphicon icon not showing, and not performing required functionality in sidebar menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, glyphicons

I am looking to add a glyphicon-menu-left icon to the sidebar of my application so that when it is clicked, the sidebar collapses to a hamburger menu icon. However with my present code the icon itself (a left arrow) does not appear, and when the button is clicked, nothing happens.
Here is the html segment with the glyphicon button:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!--Collapsable navbar-->
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Logo</span>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left leftarrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav mylist" style="align-items:center">
```

Why isn't the icon itself appearing, and why doesn't the icon perform the required functionality?
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap glyphicon-menu-hamburger not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385408/bootstrap-glyphicon-menu-hamburger-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by upgrading Bootstrap version from 3.3.1 to 3.3.7.
You should find the following code inside the bootstrap.css file

```
.glyphicon-menu-left:before {
    content: "\e257";
}
```